# How do I return the value when using async method to return the value. I am getting an error

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, async-await

The error I am getting is on the last line on return statement.

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to RestSharp.IRestResponse'. An explicit conversion exits (are you missing a cast?)"

```
public static async Task<IRestResponse<T>> ExecuteAsyncRequest<T>(this RestClient client, IRestRequest request) where T : class, new() //Since we used the T. We need to specify wether T is of type class or new type
     {

         var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();


         client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, restResponse =>
         {
             //Verbose message of the error
             if (restResponse.ErrorException != null)
             {

                 const string message = "Error retrieving response.";
                 throw new ApplicationException(message, restResponse.ErrorException);

             }

             //Setting the result of the execution
             taskCompletionSource.SetResult(restResponse);

         });

         //return us the reuslt
         return await taskCompletionSource.Task;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite reproduce this: I get a slightly different error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'RestSharp.IRestResponse' to 'RestSharp.IRestResponse'. An explicit conversion exits (are you missing a cast?)

[Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LQ5blp)

This is because your method returns an `IRestResponse<T>`, but your `TaskCompletionSource` only contains an `IRestResponse`. You can fix the error by changing it to a `TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse<T>>`.

```
var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse<T>>();
```